# Power BI - add columns / filters for date 1, date 2..date n where n is number of days between two dates

Tags: powerbi

To explain my issue please have a look at below extract from my schema.

```
ID          STATE   START_DATE_PACK END_DATE_PACK   PACK    CLOSE DATE
10539395    O       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1  
10564163    O       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1  
10564181    O       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1  
10564574    C       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1      12/10/2019
10564578    C       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1      12/10/2019
10564580    C       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1      13/10/2019
10565048    C       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1      14/10/2019
10565069    C       10/10/2019      20/10/2019      A1      15/10/2019
```

What I want it the graph that shows the progress per day (between Start & End dates).

In excel it would simple stacked chart but I am struggling to do in Power BI. Note I have hundreds of Packs hence some dynamic way of ding it is required.

[image]

**16-Oct Update**
This is my table now

```
ID          STATE   START_DATE_PACK END_DATE_PACK   PACK    CLOSE DATE  Column  NEW.DAYS_ON_CHECK_COUNT Column 2
10539395    O       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1                  Open    DAY                     8
10564163    O       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1                  Open    DAY                     8
10564181    O       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1                  Open    DAY                     8
10564574    C       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1     12/10/2019   Closed  DAY 2                   8
10564578    C       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1     12/10/2019   Closed  DAY 2                   8
10564580    C       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1     13/10/2019   Closed  DAY 3                   8
10565048    C       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1     14/10/2019   Closed  DAY 4                   8
10565069    C       10/10/2019       20/10/2019     A1     15/10/2019   Closed  DAY 5                   8
```

Where:

```
Column = IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1[CLOSE DATE]), "Open", "Close")

NEW.DAYS_ON_CHECK_COUNT = 
  VAR _days = DATEDIFF(Sheet1[START_DATE_PACK],Sheet1[CLOSE DATE], DAY)
RETURN "DAY " & _days

Column 2 = COUNTROWS(Sheet1)
```

My Graph is nearly there
[image]

Still does not work as a ratio of all and closed per day. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a **Days** table, containing 2 columns:

**Day Label** e.g. DAY 1, DAY 2, ...

**Day Datediff** e.g. 0, 1, ...

It might requires 10 rows to achieve your chart example - you may want to create it with extra rows for other scenarios. The simplest way would be using Enter Data, there are probably more elegant alternatives.

In the Model (diagram) view, the **Days** table should remain disconnected from every other table.  I would set the **Sort by Column** for the **Days Label** column to the **Day Number column**

Next I would create a new **Statuses** table, with values Open and Closed in a column **Status**. Again this table would stay disconnected in the Model.

The last disconnected table I would create is **Dates** e.g. using the CALENDARAUTO function.

Next I would create a Measure to count the relevant rows for each combination of the disconnected table rows, e.g.

```
Daily Count = 
VAR vStart_Date =
    MIN ( Dates[Date] )
VAR vEnd_Date =
    MAX ( Dates[Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        CROSSJOIN ( Sheet1, Days, Dates, Statuses ),
        SWITCH (
            TRUE,
            [Date] < vStart_Date, BLANK (),
            [Date] > vEnd_Date, BLANK (),
            [Date] < [START_DATE_PACK], BLANK (),
            [Date] > [END_DATE_PACK], BLANK (),
            DATEDIFF ( vStart_Date, [Date], DAY ) <> [Day Datediff], BLANK (),
            [Status] = "Open" 
                && [STATE] = "C" && [Date] > [CLOSE DATE] , BLANK (),
            [Status] = "Closed" 
                && [STATE] = "O", BLANK (),
            [Status] = "Closed" 
                && [Date] <= [CLOSE DATE] , BLANK (),
            1
        )
    )
```

On the page I would create a Slicer for the Dates field from the Date table, and filter for your date range (e.g. 10/10/2019 - 15/10/2019).

Finally I would add a stacked column chart, using the **Day Label** field from the **Days** table as the chart Axis, **Status** as Legend and use the measure **Days Count** as the Value.

There's parts of your requirements I can't follow from the OP, so the above might need tweaking.

I've built a working demo which you can download from this link:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AGLFDsG7h6JPgw4

The file name is: **Power BI demo - Progress per day between Start and End Dates.pbix**.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Demo chart]

Answer (score -1):

from your data you need to add a column that can be used as a legend.

If that is your schema direct from the table you can do it in Power Query or Dax

In Power Query add a custom column

```
if [Close Date] = "" Then "Open" else "Close"
```

In DAX you can add a custom column as well with the logic

```
Column = IF(ISBLANK('tablename'[Close Date]), "Open", Close")
```

You can then drag that as the legend, and the 'Start Date' as a value, with an aggregation of count, Or create a new measure with COUNT('tablename'[StartDate]) which should do the same.

Hope that helps

Update:
Your example is showing the correct split, I think you need to allocate the open items to the number of days

```
NEW.DAYS_ON_CHECK_COUNT =
  VAR dateCheck = IF(ISBLANK('Sheet1'[CLOSE DATE]), TODAY(), 'Sheet1'[CLOSE DATE])
  VAR _days = DATEDIFF(Sheet1[START_DATE_PACK],dateCheck  , DAY)
RETURN "DAY " & _days
```

That should set the open ones to the number of days open from the start date to today, So those items should appear as 'Days 6', tomorrow they will be 'Days 7' if not closed.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please review and accept if it is the correct result

Comment: @ Jonee But it is showing the same. Still missing the total value. The graph should always have 8 and see the decreasein Open items.

Comment: @ Jonee nearly there. I reckon I need another count that will be count open + count unique CLOSE DATE?

Comment: Is the progress per day a cumulative total of the other days? or just how many were done on each day?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using another visualization "100% Stacked column chart" rather?
That will have 100% chart with options like yours Open & Close.

Hope this what you are after. Let me know how you go!

[See the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8v6x.png)